# How to get remote TLS/SSL certificate when not trusted using jax-ws/SSLSocket

Tags: java, ssl, https, cxf, jax-ws

We are using a JAX-WS client over HTTPS to send messages (backed by CXF, which I think uses SSLSocket).
We wish to log the remote certificate details, together with the message details, if the remote certificate is not trusted/invalid.

Initially I hoped we would get a usefull exception, but the interesting exceptions in the stack trace are internal (like sun.security.validator.ValidatorException and sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException), so shouldn't really be used, and regardless don't seem to hold the remote certificate.

So my question is, what would be the most tidy way to get the certificate, at the level where I also have the message details (outside the JAX-WS call)?

So far my best guess is to add my own javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager, which wraps the currently used one, and puts the Certificate on a ThreadLocal, where the caller can lately pick it up. It doesn't seem very tidy, but it's the best that seems possible so far :)

Many thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

The main point is that JSSE is doing and hiding all of the things you are looking for, in your question. But luckily it seems that CXF allows some customization.
The idea is to customize the SSLSocketFactory ( http://cxf.apache.org/docs/tls-configuration.html#TLSConfiguration-ClientTLSParameters ) with your own implementation, and this one must create [Sockets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html) that come with your own [HandshakeCompletedListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HandshakeCompletedListener.html). This is this last object which will dump the information that you are looking for, I give you an implementation example :

```
class CustomHandshakeCompletedListener implements HandshakeCompletedListener {
  private HandshakeCompletedEvent hce;
  private String cipher;
  private Certificate[] peerCertificates = null;
  private Principal peerPrincipal = null;

  public void handshakeCompleted(HandshakeCompletedEvent hce) {
    this.hce = hce;

    // only cipersuites different from DH_anon* will return a server certificate
    if(!cipher.toLowerCase().contains("dh_anon")) {
      try {
        cipher = hce.getCipherSuite();
        peerCertificates = hce.getPeerCertificates();
        peerPrincipal = hce.getPeerPrincipal();
        // do anything you want with these certificates and ciphersuite
      }
      catch(SSLPeerUnverifiedException spue) {
        System.err.println("unexpected exception :");
        spue.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
```

There is still some work to achieve your goal, let us know if it's working well this clue.

Comment: Is a HandshakeCompletedEvent fired when the certificate is not trusted, and the connection thus is not made though?

Comment: I believe that yes because the handshake was done, closing the connection is a client initiative after that. I can test later with some code of my own if you want a confirmation.

Comment: Thank you! But yeah, it makes sense, as it provides information only available after a successful handshake. So for the best still seems to extend X509TrustManager, either putting the cert on a ThreadLocal, or throwing our own CertificateException from it with the certificate as field.

Comment: I agree with your interpretation.